# How to fix a file-dialog that keeps reopenning after a file have been choosen in python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

im new to pyqt5 and i need help with closing an file dialog in my application. The UI is created using QT designer. When I choose a file and press the open button the file dialog first closes but then reopens again. That is my problem. It should not reopen.

I have tried to use these following functions on the dialog `fileDialog.close()` and `fileDialog.hide()`, but have not managed to get it to work properly.

I use two different files, one that is for the main window and the other is for the file dialog. From the main window i use the following class

```
class Main (QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('MainWindow.ui', self)

        self.btnChooseFile.clicked.connect(self.chooseFile)

    def chooseFile(self):
        fileDialog = OpenFileDialog.FileDialog()
        fileDialog.openFileNameDialog()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
win = Main()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The other class looks is called OpenFileDialog.py and looks like this:

```
class FileDialog(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(FileDialog, self).__init__()
        self.title = 'Choose image-file'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.openFileNameDialog()
        self.openFileNamesDialog()
        self.saveFileDialog()

        self.show()

    def openFileNameDialog(self):    
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            print(fileName)


    def openFileNamesDialog(self):    
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
        if files:
            print(files)


    def saveFileDialog(self):    
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()","","All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            print(fileName)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FileDialog()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The UI File looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>winMain</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="winMain">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>280</width>
    <height>320</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>280</width>
    <height>320</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>280</width>
    <height>320</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>OCR</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnChooseFile">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>93</width>
      <height>28</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Choose file</string>
    </property>
   </widget>

   <widget class="QLabel" name="lblFile">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>31</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-weight:600;&quot;&gt;File:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="lblFilePath">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>221</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-style:italic;&quot;&gt;FilePath&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>280</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**
I Fixed the problem by removing the following line of code in the chooseFile-function:

```
fileDialog.openFileNameDialog()
```

Comment: @user9402680 I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If I remove two of those three  lines in the initUI function, then it will not reopen more than once?

Comment: @user9402680 Thank you anyways! I tried to do also but it didn't work either.

Comment: @user9402680 `self.btnChooseFile.clicked.connect(self.chooseFile)` it's the way I use to connect a button to a specific function. Should I do it another way?

Comment: To be honest, I don't have a clue to solve your problem.I recommend you also upload your ui file because only these codes are not executable.More Knowledge persons will answer.I'm sorry, I can't help you,I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

**maun.py**

```
import sys
import os                                              # +++
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class FileDialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FileDialog, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Choose image-file')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 640, 480)

#        self.openFileNameDialog()
#        self.openFileNamesDialog()
#        self.saveFileDialog()

    def openFileNameDialog(self):    
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                      "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", 
                      "",
                      "All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", 
                      options=options)
        if fileName:
            print("fileName->", fileName)
            return fileName                                      # +++

    def openFileNamesDialog(self):    
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self,
                   "QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()", 
                   "",
                   "All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", 
                   options=options)
        if files:
            print("files -->>", files)
            return files                                          # +++

    def saveFileDialog(self):    
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,
                      "QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()",
                      "",
                      "All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)", 
                      options=options)
        if fileName:
            print("save fileName->", fileName)
            return fileName                                        # +++


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        uic.loadUi('MainWindow.ui', self)

        self.btnChooseFile.clicked.connect(self.chooseFile)
        self.btnChooseFile_2.clicked.connect(self.chooseFiles)     # +++
        self.btnChooseFile_3.clicked.connect(self.saveFile)        # +++

    def chooseFile(self):
#        fileDialog = OpenFileDialog.FileDialog()
        fileDialog = FileDialog()
        fileName = fileDialog.openFileNameDialog()
        self.lblFile.setText( "<b>File:</b> {}".format( os.path.basename(fileName) ))
        self.lblFilePath.setText( "<b>FilePath:</b> {}".format( os.path.dirname(fileName) ))

    def chooseFiles(self):
        fileDialog = FileDialog()
        files = fileDialog.openFileNamesDialog()
        fileNames = ", ".join([ os.path.basename(fileName) for fileName in files ])
        self.lblFile.setText( "<b>Files:</b> {}".format( os.path.basename(fileNames) ))
        self.lblFilePath.setText( "<b>FilePath:</b> {}".format( os.path.dirname(files[0]) ))    

    def saveFile(self):
        fileDialog = FileDialog()
        fileName = fileDialog.saveFileDialog()
        self.lblFile.setText( "<b>Save File:</b> {}".format( os.path.basename(fileName) ))
        self.lblFilePath.setText( "<b>FilePath:</b> {}".format( os.path.dirname(fileName) ))    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    win = Main()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**MainWindow.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>winMain</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="winMain">
  <property name="enabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>380</width>
    <height>380</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>380</width>
    <height>320</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>OCR</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnChooseFile">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>93</width>
      <height>28</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Choose file</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="lblFile">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>70</y>
      <width>321</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-weight:600;&quot;&gt;File:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="lblFilePath">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>321</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-style:italic;&quot;&gt;FilePath&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnChooseFile_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>140</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>93</width>
      <height>28</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Choose files</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnChooseFile_3">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>260</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>93</width>
      <height>28</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Save file</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>380</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly and also fixed the problem i had with adding the complete path to the 'FilePath' label

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to design it in the designer or make a separate class, If you need a standard file-dialog.

All you have to do is

1. import QFileDialog in your Main
2. Write a single function that will open a standard file dialog:

```
def open_file_dialog(self):
    # Just this line will open a standard file dialog for you
    res = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(QFileDialog(self), # parent 
                                      "Select file", # Dialog title
                                      "/some/path/to/open/by/default",
                                      "JPEG Image (*.jpeg)") # filter

    # Once you reach here - dialog will be closed
    if res == ('', ''):
        print("Cancelled")
    else:
        self.process_result(res)
```

3. Connect the button click event with the function above, just as you do it.